# How to specify specific (custom) function arguments

Tags: functions, function-construction, argument-patterns

Suppose that I want to have a function that is evaluated only when a user-specific, predefined flag is given out of a list of possible flags. For example

```
Clear[flags];
flags = {fyes, fno};

Clear[testf];
testf[flag_:flags] := 
  If[flag === fyes, Print["yes"], Print["no"]];
```

I am aware that the above snippet is wrong but that's the closest that I could get.
`testf` should be evaluated only if `flag` is either `fyes` or `fno` and stay unevaluated for any other argument.
How is this possible to be achieved?

Comment: `testf[flag_ /; MemberQ[flags, flag]] := 
  If[flag === fyes, Print["yes"], Print["no"]];`

Comment: Additionally, I would say that a function should not be reliant on a global variable; so please elaborate a bit further, if you consider it worthwhile.

Comment: Hi, and thank you. Well that's the point of a flag, right? To be a global variable "known" to the whole notebook such that it allows for specific situations...

Comment: try `testf[flag_: Alternatives @@ flags] := ...`?